# Is it possible to have a bash-like command history for the clisp interpreter?

Tags: history, clisp

I use the GNU CLISP 2.49 Interpreter. When I start evaluating expressions I may cycle through them with the up and down arrow keys. However, when I quit and restart, none of them are available. Is there a way to have a command-history across sessions within CLISP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Advanced Readline and History Functionality](http://clisp.org/impnotes/readline-mod.html) and [examples](http://clisp.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/clisp/clisp/modules/readline/test.tst):

```
(defparameter *history-file* "readline-history-file")
(readline:write-history *history-file*)            
(readline:append-history 1000 *history-file*)      
(readline:read-history *history-file*)            
(readline:read-history-range *history-file* 0 -1)  
(readline:history-truncate-file *history-file* 10)
```

Comment: This answer is vague and does not provide any context; moreover, the example (link) provided is not an example configuration, but a test file.  An example taken from a working configuration file would be a nice addition and would solidify this answer quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

On my Mac I use `rlwrap` with the `--always-readline` option:

```
rlwrap --always-readline clisp
```

Answer (score 1):

It is ironic that rlwrap is being recommended as a solution for `clisp`, as `clisp` [famously](https://github.com/JoshCheek/clisp/blob/master/doc/Why-CLISP-is-under-GPL) adopted the GPL precisely because it links against readline, giving it much better (context-aware) completion than `rlwrap` ever could. Citing `rlwrap`s manpage:

```
BUGS and LIMITATIONS
   Though it is flexible, delivers the goods (readline functionality), and adheres 
   to  the  Unix  "many  small  tools"  paradigm, rlwrap  is a kludge. It cannot 
   know anything about command's internal state, which makes context-sensitive 
   completion impossible. Using the readline library from within command is 
   still the best option.
```

Apparently, persistent history has to be configured (see sds' answer), which could be tricky for a new user, but after that, you'll have a much cleverer command line than with `rlwrap`